# Standardise by sub-group mean or overall mean?

Tags: standard-deviation, standardization

I am looking at the difference between genders on a mobility metric and I would like to evaluate the temporal patterns of this metric, I have already assessed the differences in the distributions, and volumes.

My objective is to plot a box plot per day of the week (or month, or hour of the day) for each gender and compare how the IQR and median change with each day.

If I want to compare the differences between the genders of the patterns, should I:
A) Standardise using the mean and std dev of the metric?

> (X-mean_all)/std_all

B) Or instead use the mean and std dev specific for each gender?

> (X-mean_F)/std_F
> (X-mean_M)/std_M

Are the results comparable when standardising by subgroup?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you mean to _subtract_ the means rather than _divide_ by them.

Comment: yes, I have updated the description.